# In my app can i add ads if my sponsor using iAd

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, iad

For my app  can i display ads of my sponsor alone using iAd?

for eg: "X" has agreed to sponsor my app. So can i add ads of "X" alone in my app?
Do i have any control over the ads shown through my app or is it decided by Apple?

Answer (score 2):

Apple lets you decide which advertisers **exclude** from the banners (i.e. if you have competitors that are advertising through iAd too), but at the moment there is no possibility of defining a set of "accepted" advertisers. Only a set of "excluded" advertisers can be defined.

You should migrate to another advertising library/platform different from iAd.

Answer (score -3):

http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/fundamentals.html

use this link

and use

[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

this code is replace by

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

```
[request setTesting:TRUE];

[bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

Check it and replay

Comment: This is not related to iAd. Maybe you should find an appropriate solution to the question.

Comment: use publish id ,  r u have  publish id